# how to get a return type of a member function pointer

Tags: c++, type-traits, pointer-to-member, decltype

Is there a way to determine a return type of a member function pointer?

Code sample:

```
///// my library
void my_func(auto mptr) { // have to use `auto`
  // some logic based on a return type of mptr: int, string, A, etc.
}

///// client code
struct A {
  int foo();
  std::string bar(int);
};

class B{
public:
  A func(int, double);
};
// ... and many other classes

my_func(&A::foo);
my_func(&A::bar);
my_func(&B::func);
// ... many other calls of my_func()
```

I need to "fill in" `my_func()`.

Edit:
I can't use `std::result_of`/`std::invoke_result` as I don't know the full list of parameters of `mptr`. It's not important with which params a method is supposed to be called as I'm not calling it. I would like to avoid creating an object of base class of `mptr` even if I'm able to determine it (using `declval` is ok).

Comment: Even if you could get the return type, how are you planning on using it? You can't call `mptr()` as you don't know what parameters it takes.  Your examples have different parameter lists.

Comment: Why do you _have_ to use `auto`? Are templates forbidden in your code base? In that case, you can't use `auto` there either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I don't want to make my example to complex. Lets say I need to declare a variable of `mptr` return type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I can modify `my_func()` signature as I wish. However I can't change the way it's called. It get's generated by preprocessor instructions in the code I can't alter.

Comment: Describe "some logic". What are you going to do with the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use partial template specialization to determine the return type of `mptr`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ReturnType;

template <typename Object, typename Return, typename... Args>
struct ReturnType<Return (Object::*)(Args...)>
{
    using Type = Return;
};

void my_func(auto mptr) {
  typename ReturnType<decltype(mptr)>::Type obj;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7761cff81061d3d)

Comment: You can use partial template specialization to do anything, tbh

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if the member function has a cv-qualifier or a ref-qualifier or is C-style variadic or is marked `noexcept`. See the nasty "possible implementation" on [cppreference's `is_function` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function#Possible_implementation).

Comment: @aschepler Thankfully member functions and objects I have to deal with are more or less follow a "template" so I was able to use `ReturnType` with only minor changes

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that deduces the type of a member function pointer, and returns the deduced return type. Note that only a declaration, and no definition is needed

```
template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
auto ret_type(Ret (C::*)(Args...)) -> Ret;

void my_func(auto mptr) 
{ 
  using type = decltype(ret_type(mptr));
}
```

In my opinion, this is also easier to read than the specialization solution.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5so6T7Mrr)

You can also account for *cv*-qualifiers by adding overloads. e.g.

```
template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
auto ret_type(Ret (C::*)(Args...) const) -> Ret;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/McTWcff1z)

Comment: @MaximKirov No problem. Note that you can only pick one answer at most to accept (I notice you tried accepting this one), so pick whichever one you like the most. You can always upvote multiple answers if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with which seems to work for most cases.

```
template <typename TYPE, typename FUNCPTR, typename...ARGS>
using mfunc_return_t = decltype((std::declval<TYPE>().*std::declval<FUNCPTR>())(std::declval<ARGS&>()...));
```

Then I use it in a function which calls a provided member function.

```
template <typename FUNCPTR, typename TYPE, typename...ARGS>
mfunc_return_t<TYPE, FUNCPTR, ARGS...> SafeCall(TYPE* ptr, FUNCPTR func, ARGS&...args)
{
    if (ptr != nullptr)
        return (ptr->*func)(args...);
    using ReturnType = mfunc_return_t<TYPE, FUNCPTR, ARGS...>;
    return DefaultValue<ReturnType>();
}
```

I have several implementation of DefaultValue for handling types including arithmetic types, pointers, void, and other default constructable types.

Then I can do things like

```
return SafeCall(pointer, &MyClass::FunctionName, arg1, arg2);
```